# Apply className In datatables html equations

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, datatables

Hi I have a fn created row in my datatables with if condition if i gave a classname in column its working fine but when I try to give that class name in if condition datatable is not displaying could any one tell me to how to apply className in created rows. this is my code

```
var due_amount=aData['name'];
        if(aData['due'] != ""  && aData['id'] == aData['base_id'] && aData['status'] != "Active" )
        {
            due = '<span class="label label-red">'+aData['name']+'</span>';
        }
```

Comment: Does it work with a couple more parenthesis, like this : `if( (aData['due'] != "")  && (aData['id'] == aData['base_id']) && (aData['status'] != "Active") )` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a couple more parenthesis.

```
if( (aData['due'] != "")  && (aData['id'] == aData['base_id']) && (aData['status'] != "Active") )
```

What I often do to make a complex condition more readeable is this:

```
if( (aData['due'] != "")  && 
    (aData['id'] == aData['base_id']) && 
    (aData['status'] != "Active")
  )
```

On multiple lines, missing characters or logic mistakes are easier to find.
;)

Bonus question in comment:

If you split your things on multiple lines, it easier:

```
[ 
    {
    "title": "S. No.",
    "name":"sno",
    "orderable": false,
    "className":'details-control',
    "data":"sno",
    "width":"7%" 
    },              // Remove this comma !
],
```

**Last bonus question:**
To add a class to a `<td>` where due_amount var is used to append it:
*(If I correctly understood, the last comment)*

Try to use a new class in the span (I used `bgAppended`) for the example,
Or use an existing one (I didn't see your code...)

In order to do it via jQuery.

```
due_amount = '<span class="label label-red bgAppended">'+aData['father_name']+'</span>';
```

Do this **after** the appending:

```
$(".bgAppended").closest("td").addClass("details-control");
```

Comment: my problem is  "columns": [
            { "title": "S. No.", "name":"sno", "orderable": false, "className":'details-control',  "data":"sno", "width":"7%" }, ],

Comment: I want to apply that className in if condition how to apply

Comment: I answered... I hope it is the fix.

Comment: if((aData['dume_amount'] != "") 
    && (aData['student_id'] == aData['student_fees_id'])
   && (aData['status'] != "Enrolled")
    "className":'details-control')
            {
                due_amount = '<span class="label label-red">'+aData['father_name']+'</span>';
   }
            $(nRow).find('td:eq(2)').html(due_amount);

Comment: I dont need that class name in columns i need ily in if condition @Louys Patrice Bessette

Comment: Could you please modify your answer i am not getting any result

Comment: This is another code chunk... I dont get what you what to do with `"className":'details-control'`.

Comment: td.details-control {
    background: url('<?php echo base_url();?>/assets/details_open.png') no-repeat center right;
    cursor: pointer;
}
tr.shown td.details-control {
    background: url('<?php echo base_url();?>assets/details_close.png') no-repeat center right;
}

Comment: You want to apply the `details-control` class to a `td` wich is a parent to the `<span>` you happen  (I suppose you do this) ?